# Regular expression for allowing only 1 of a set of characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use some regex to validate some input inside of Java code.  I have been successful in implementing "basic" regex, but this one seems to be out of my scope of knowledge.  I am working through RegEgg tutorials to learn more.

Here are the conditions that need to be validated:

- Field will always have 8 characters
- Can be all spaces

Or

- Valid characters: a-zA-Z0-9 -!& or a space
- Cannot begin with a space
- If one of the special characters is used, it can be the only one used
  Legal:   "B-123---"    "AB&&   &"  "A!!!!!!!"
  Illegal: "B-123!!!"    "AB&&   -"  "A-&!    "
- Has to have at least one alphanumeric character (Can't be all special characters ie: "!!!!!!!!"

This was my regex before additional validations were added:

```
^(\s{8}|[A-Za-z\-\!\&][ A-Za-z0-9\-\!\&]{7})$"
```

Then the additional validations for now allowing multiple of the special characters, and I am a bit stuck.  I have been successful in using a positive lookahead, but stuck when trying to use the positive lookbehind. (I think the data before the lookbehind was consumed), but I am speculating as I am a neophyte with this part of regex.

Comment: Could you just run both regexs separately, and then use a conditional to determine if one or the other is triggered? Even if that does not solve the problem, it simplifies it (presumably it is the second case that is trickier).

Comment: Now that you've described a valid set, can you also include what is invalid because sometimes valid is used synonymous with required.

Comment: Once you learn how to do this with a Regex, you might decide it's much simpler to enforce the constraints with normal Java code.

Answer (score 2):

using the or construct (`a|b`) is a large part of this, and you've begun applying it, so that's a good start.

You've made the rule that it can't start with a digit; nothing in the spec says this. also, `-` inside `[]` has special meaning, so escape it, or make sure it is first or last, because then you don't have to. That gets us to:

`^(\s{8}|[A-Za-z0-9-!& -]{8})$`

next up is the rule that it has to be all the same special character if used at all. Given that there are only 3 special characters, could be easier to just explicitly list them all:

`^(\s{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 -]{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 !]{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 &]{8})$`

Next up: Can't start with a space, and can't be all-special. Confirming the negative (that it ISNT all-special characters) gets complicated; lookahead seems like a better plan here. This:

`^` is regexp-ese for: "Start of line". Note that this doesn't 'consume' a character. `1` is regexpese for 'only the exact character '1' will match here, nothinge else', but as it matches, it also 'consumes' that character, whereas `^` doesn't do that. 'start of line' is not a concept that can be consumed.

This notion of 'a match may fail, but if it succeeds, nothing is consumed' isn't limited to `^` and `$`; you can write your own:

`(?=abc)` will match if `abc` would match at this position, **but does not consume it**. Thus, the regexp `^(=abc)ab.d$` would match the input string `abcd` and nothing else. This is called **positive lookahead**. (it 'looks ahead' and matches if it sees the regular expression in the parens, failing if it does not).

`(?!abc)` is **negative lookahead**. It matches if it DOESNT see the thing in the parens. `(?!abc)a.c` will match the input `adc` but not the input `abc`.

`(?<=abc)` is **positive lookbehind**. It matches if the pattern you provide would match such that the match *ends* at the position you find yourself.

`(?<!abc)` is **negative lookbehind**.

Note that lookahead and lookbehind can be somewhat limited, in that they may not allow variable length patterns. But, fortunately, your requirements make it easy to limit ourselves to fixed size patterns here. Thus, we can introduce: `(?![&!-]{8})` as a non-consuming unit in our regexp that will fail the match if we have all-8 special characters.

We can use this trick to fail on starting space too: `(?! )` is all we need for that one.

Let's replace `\s` which is *whitespace* with just   which is the space character (the problem description says 'space', not 'whitespace').

Putting it all together:

`^( {8}|(?! )(?![&!-]{8})([A-Za-z0-9 -]{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 !]{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 &]{8}))$`

Thats:

1. 8 spaces, or...
2. not a space, and not all-8 special character, then,
3. any of the valid chars, any amount of spaces, and any amount of one of the 3 allowed special symbols, as long as we have precisely 8 of them...
4. .. OR the same thing as #3 but with the second of the three special symbols
5. .. OR with the third of the three.

Plug em in at [regex101](https://regex101.com) along with your various examples of 'legal' and 'not legal' and you can play around with it some more.

NB: You can also use backreferences to attempt to solve the 'only one special character is allowed' part of this, but attempting to tackle the 'not all special characters' part seems quite unwieldy if you don't get to use (negative) lookahead.

Comment: I can't thank you enough!  Not just for a solution that works, but for the fantastic explanation. This has helped in my learning!  Thank you!

Comment: FYI...There was one issue with the REGEX above...
It was allowing:  !!! !!!!

At least one alphanumeric has to be in the string if not all blanks.

I fixed it by doing:
^( {8}|(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*)(?![0-9])(?! )(?![&!-]{8})([A-Za-z0-9 -]{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 !]{8}|[A-Za-z0-9 &]{8}))$

Again, thank you!

Comment: I am going to have to learn how to format my comments in stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of asserting the right conditions at the start of the regex.

`^(?=[ ]*$|(?![ ]))(?!.*([!&-]).*(?!\1)[!&-])[a-zA-Z0-9 !&-]{8}$`

see -> https://regex101.com/r/tN5y4P/1

Some discussion:

```
 ^                      # Begin of text
 (?=                    # Assert, cannot start with a space
      [ ]* $            # unless it's all spaces
   |  (?! [ ] )
 )
 (?!                    # Assert, not mixed special chars
      .* 
      ( [!&-] )         # (1)
      .* 
      (?! \1 )
      [!&-] 
 )
 [a-zA-Z0-9 !&-]{8}     # Consume 8 valid characters from within this class
 $                      # End of text
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in helping me with my issue!  This solution was allowing all 8 characters to be special, so I added: (?![&!-]{8})  to the beginning. This took care of it.

I really don't fully understand the regex for the special character checks. It works though!

I think it means
Negative lookahead
Allow characters until a special character

(?!                    # Assert, not mixed special chars
      .* 
      ( [!&-] )         # (1)
      .* 
      (?! \1 )
      [!&-] 
 )

Comment: I think it means
Negative lookahead
Allow all characters until a special character
Special character becomes the data for \1
Allow all characters again until a special character
Don't allow any special character that does not match \1
Then I don't understand:  [!&-] 

(?!                    # Assert, not mixed special chars
      .* 
      ( [!&-] )         # (1)
      .* 
      (?! \1 )
      [!&-] 
 )

Comment: I see that you have a little trouble understanding this critical section `(?!.*([!&-]).*(?!\1)[!&-])`. So here's some    keys to figuring it out. First of all, anything inside off here `(?!---)` is a group conditional assertion. The  contents, `---` are just a normal expression that the _engine_ WANTS to match really bad !! It basically finds the first special character `([!&-])`  then another special character that _IS NOT_ the _first_ one it matched `(?!\1)[!&-]` it uses a negative lookahead to insure it is not the first one.

Comment: (con't) So if `---`  didn't match it means it did not find different special characters `[!&-]`. The assertion is checked _AFTER_ the expression is done for pass or fail. It does not influence the backtrack mechanism at all meaning the expression is _Atomic_

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked `Has to have at least one alphanumeric character (Can't be all special characters ie: "!!!!!!!!"` this in your post . It looks like you're accepting the other answer so no need to update my answer.

Comment: Yes!  I did not understand it very well at all!  Thanks for the explanation!  It helps me learn!

Comment: Yes, well @MrBill, if you plan on learning regex, moving forward, the piece I explained is one of the most _powerful and important_ concept to understand in all regex. I would re-read it at least 14 times if I were you.